# Property testing algorithm for isomorphism to a balanced 3-sided complete graph

Tags: graph-algorithms, graph-isomorphism, graph-colouring

I am looking for testing algorithm in the dense graph model, that checks for a graph with $3n$ vertices whether it's isomorphic to a balanced 3-sided complete graph with $n$ vertices in each set. The testing algorithm should do $O(\frac{1}{\epsilon^2})$ queries when $\epsilon$ is the distance.

A ***balanced 3-sided complete graph***, also known as a ***complete tripartite graph*** or a ***3-partite complete graph***, is a specific type of graph that consists of three disjoint sets of vertices, and every vertex in one set is connected to every vertex in each of the other two sets. In other words, it is a complete graph where the vertices are partitioned into three groups, and there are no edges within the same group but every vertex has edges to all vertices in the other two groups.

In the ***dense graph model***, the graph is presented as a adjacency matrix and a query as simply asking for two vertices $u,v$ whether $(u,v)$ is an edge in the graph.

I've read several articles about algorithms for testing isomorphism for k-partitioned graph but with higher query complexity. One approach is to check wither we can find a parition for 3 sets such that each set is with $n$ vertices and edges exists $\iff$ vertices are in different sets. Yet, I have no idea how to proceed.